# Move Wakari Notebooks to another directory

Tags: python, ipython, continuum

I cannot find an option to move notebooks from the home directory do other directories in wakari.
I have a bunch of notebook as mini-examples i created, and now i want to categorize them into directories i created.
Is there a way? I do not want to download them and then reupload them. 
Is there a terminal solution?

Answer (score 2):

There two ways (as far as I know) of moving files to different directories (folders):

1. Drag&Drop

   - Under every tab (upper part of the site) you have a big singe "IP[y]:Notebook" (in the same row as the "Logout" button). Click on this and you will see a kind of panel where you can change directories (move files to different folders) by dragging and dropping them.
2. Second way is to use Terminals tab and type commands like in Linux environment.

   - First check your working directory (just to know where you are at the moment):

     `In [1]: pwd
     Out[1]: u'/user_home/w_mzbik'`

     where 'mzbik' is my userName
   - Than list the files in the working directory:

     `In [2]: ls
     Lecture_1_Introduction_to_Python_Programming.ipynb next.ml_demo.ipynb  wakaripython/ ParallelProgramming/ scripts/`
   - Now suppose you would like to move next.ml_demo.ipynb to ParallelProgramming folder. You have to type:

     `In [3]: mv next.ml_demo.ipynb ParallelProgramming`
   - If you would like to move more than one file you can use this:

     `mv file1 file2 file3 dir1`
   - You can find some more information about this Linux commands on the [linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0050.php)

B/R 
Michal